# Strategies for "Always-Connected" Windows Client Data Architecture

Tags: postgresql, architecture, winforms, wcf-data-services

Let me start by saying: this is my 1st post here, this is a bit lenghty, and I havent done Windows Forms development in years....with that in mind please excuse me if this isn't directly a programming question and please bear with me as I really need the help!!

I have been asked to develop a Windows Forms app for our company that talks to a central (local area network) Linux Server hosting a PostgreSQL database.  The app is to allow users to authenticate themselves into the system and thereafter conduct the usual transactions with the PG database. Ordinarily, I would propose writing a webforms app against Mono, but the clients need to utilise local resources such as USB peripheral devices, so that is out of the question.  While it might not seem clear, my questions **are** *italised* below:

#### Dilemma #1:

The application is meant to be always connected. *How should I structure my DAL/BLL - Should this reside on the server or with the client*?

#### Dilemma #2:

I have been reading up on [Client Application Services (CAS)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384339.aspx), and it seems like a great fit for authentication, as everything is exposed via URIs.  I know that a .NET Data Provider exists for PostgreSQL, but *not too sure if CAS will all work on a Linux (Debian) server*?  Believe me, I would get my hands dirty and try myself, but I need to come up with a logical design first before resources are allocated to me for "trial purposes"!

#### Dilemma #3:

If the DAL/BLL is to reside on the server, is there any way I can create data services, and expose only these services to authenticated clients.  There is a (security) requirement whereby a connection string with username and password to the database cannot be present on any client machines...even if security on the database side is quite rigid.  I'm guessing that the only way for this to work would be to create the various CRUD data service methods that are exposed by an ASP.NET app, and have the WindowsForms make a request for data or persist data to the ASP.NET app (thru a URI) and have that return a resultset or value.  *Would I be correct in assuming this? Should I be looking into WCF Data Services? and will WCF work with a non-SQL Server database?*

Thank you for taking the time out to read this, but know that I am desperately seeking any advice on this!  THANKS A MILLION!!!!

#### EDIT:

I am considering also using NHibernate as my ORM

Comment: The URL for the PostgreSQL .NET data provider is: http://npgsql.projects.postgresql.org/

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say "always connected"?

Comment: I mean, that unlike a Smart-Client which is occassionally connected (to a central DB server, for instance), due to the business requirements of this app, it must always be connected to live data - else it cannot allow the user to continue.  "If the person is busy working with something and the connection drops for whatever reason then too bad" ... to quote our analyst! yep, thats the mentality I gotta put up with!

Answer (score 0):

Some parts of your questions are complicated and beyond my expertise.  However, in general you can do almost anything you put effort into, CAP theorem and the like aside.

DAL/BLL stuff in general can reside in any of the tiers.  I put a lot of this in my database and some in the middle tier, however this is to allow re-use in different environments which may or may not be a goal for you.  The thing is I would think through carefully the separation of concerns issues here and what sorts of centralization of logic you want to place.  The further back, the more re-usable this becomes but this is not always a free tradeoff.

I am not entirely familiar with CAS but it looked like AJAX kinds of stuff from what I saw on the MSDN web site.  That could be wrong, but if it is right, then you have an issue in that such requests may be stateless and this could be an issue if you need a constant connection.

On the whole based on what you are saying it sounds cleanest to do a two tier rather than a three tier app, and have the DAL/BLL sit on the client, possibly supported by stored procedures in the server.  You can then set PostgreSQL up to authenticate against whatever you use on your network (KRB5 if AD is what I would recommend).  This simplifies your data access, and it allows you to control permissions based on the authentication against the database.  Since you can authenticate users based on AD, you can then set permissions accordingly.

One important consideration is going to be number of connections.  PostgreSQL does have some places where every current connection must be checked and iterated through, and connection startup and tear-down overhead in some cases can be significant.  So one important decision will involve connection pooling.  Whether or not you use connection pooling to boost performance will depend on what you are doing but I have seen cases where PostgreSQL has handled 600 connections without serious problems.